# GWT applications and the returned response from the server

Tags: java, gwt, pingdom

I have some GWT application that run on the server.

we are subscripting with some solution that pings this application in a regular interval of time.
The point is, this solution (service) checks the returned response from the server to contain some pre-defined keywords.

But as you know, GWT return plain empty HTML page with the data contained in the .js file.

So, the Ping service will not be able to exmain the pre-defined keywords, Is this statement true??

And if this is ture, cannot we find any workaround solution to solve such problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the crawlabitlity of AJAX applications - [Google has some pointers](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html) for you :) Generally, you need a headless browser on the server to generate the output you'd normally see in the browser, for example see [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Only the initial container page and the loader script that it embeds are HTML & JS. Afterwards, you use GWT's RPC mechanism to exchange Java objects with the server, or Ajax (eg. RequestBuilder) to exchange any kind of data with the server. you name it: JSON, XML, plain text, etc.

Comment: This is not what I am asking about, please re-read the question! I am asking `is there any workarounds for making the server sends the actual HTML to the client` ??

Comment: Please rework your question. It is not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve (Some kind of challenge-response authentication? Sending some simple html strings to the client?) We need some more input.

Comment: +1 z00bs: I've re-read the question, and I still fail to see how it could be interpreted to mean what you've explained in your comment.